# epubcheck with error while using tex4ebook and \nocite bibtexing

Tags: biblatex, tex4ebook, epub

While running biblatex with `\nocite` commands, I got the following error message(s) when running `epubcheck` after `tex4ebook`.

```
ERROR(RSC-005): Testfile.epub/OEBPS/Testfileli3.html(19,88): Validierungsfehler: Der Wert des Attributs "id" ist ungültig; es muss ein XML-Name ohne Doppelpunkte sein

Translated:
validation error: The value of attribute "id" is invalid; is has to be a XML-name without colon
```

The MWE would be the following, but it only reproduced the error 1 time. In my sourcefile.tex I got 175 \nocite commands and got 173 identical error messages with epubcheck.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{sigfridsson}
\nocite{westfahl:space}
\nocite{set}
\nocite{stdmodel}
\nocite{aksin}
\nocite{bertram}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Is there a fix for it? --> Yes, see Answer 1. It worked reducing the epubcheck error number from 123 to 20.

**Update 1**

I now have 20 errors left with epubcheck, which seem all related to the `\pageref{somelabel}` command. epubcheck gives `ERROR(RSC-012) Fragmentbezeichner ist nicht angegeben` and points to the following example in the html files (out of the 20):

```
(wie vorangehend, bei Andrej
Sacharow<a id='dx17-18004'></a> ab Seite <a href='#x11-12001r9'>249<!--  tex4ht:ref: AndrejSacharow   --></a>, gesehen und angedeutet)
```

and points to the page number "249". But this `\pageref` is located in ordinary body of text, without embedding in other command and env.

Up to now it was not possible to reproduce the epubcheck error in a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should be fixed by `make4ht` DOM filters, but I found that this particular filter is broken. I've fixed that in `make4ht` sources, bur if you don't want to update it, you can use this build file instead:

```
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local allowed_chars = {
  ["-"] = true,
  ["."] = true
}
local function fix_colons(id)
  -- match every non alphanum character
  return id:gsub("[%W]", function(s)
    -- some characters are allowed, we don't need to replace them
    if allowed_chars[s] then return s end
    -- in other cases, replace with underscore
    return "_"
  end)
end

local function id_colons(obj)
  -- replace : characters in links and ids with unserscores
  obj:traverse_elements(function(el) 
    local name = string.lower(obj:get_element_name(el))
    if name == "a" then
      local href = el:get_attribute("href")
      -- don't replace colons in external links
      if href and not href:match("[a-z]%://") then
        local base, id = href:match("(.*)%#(.*)")
        if base and id then
          id = fix_colons(id)
          el:set_attribute("href", base .. "#" .. id)
        end
      end
    end
    local id  = el:get_attribute("id")
    if id then
      el:set_attribute("id", fix_colons(id))
    end
  end)
  return obj
end


local process = domfilter {id_colons}

Make:match("html$", process)
```

Compile using:

I also found another issue, and that is a wrong formatting of DOI numbers. It can be fixed using this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\nolinkurl#1{#1}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Compile using:

```
$ tex4ebook -e build.lua -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Michal. I updated `tex4ht` right now and tried `tex4ebook -a debug -c config.cfg -e build.lua Mysource.tex`. It gets an epub file. But with epubcheck still 173 error messages of above sort appear. I think, as we had recently, I will and need to wait for another update in `tlmgr update --list` vor `make4ht`.

Comment: @Thomkrates the build file should replace all wrong characters in `id`, you shouldn't get errors now.

Comment: Yes, with one of my sourcefile.tex it worked and I got a valid epub with epubcheck. - But with my other two projects I get the error message "error illegal storage address", and this can not be solved by changing the font (I tried 3 of them), which was some days ago a solution. I now do not get an epub with running `tex4ebook -a debug -c Myconfig.cfg -e build.lua -m index Mysourcename.tex`.

Comment: It seems to me as if this file `-e build.lua` from your answer, Michal, does not work when both biber and xindy is needed in the `-e makefile.mk4`. Since I get no epub output when using `-e build.lua`. But when running `mymakefile.mk4 with biber and xindy in it` an epub output is given, but then with error messages in epubcheck. So I think `build.lua` needs to be adjusted to this need. Without the need of both, epubcheck generated a valid epub file out of another sourcename.tex when using your `-e build.lua` file from above.

Comment: @Thomkrates yes, you will need to join build files, if you want to run also `xindy` and `biber`. I think you can just copy the older build file with instrucitons for Xindy and Biber at the end of this one.

Comment: Yes, Michal, thank you, it works this way, and reduced the error messages in epubcheck from 123 to 20. These 20 error messages left seem to have to do with the `\pageref{somelabel}` command, I looked it in the `html files` and found that always `\pageref` complaints are to be found. The error is `ERROR(RSC-012):` with epubchek and in german `Fragmentbezeichner ist nicht angegeben`. But in the `html file` the page nummer is given. Do you know again a fix for it?

Comment: @Thomkrates that's good to hear that it mostly helped. I think I will need a MWE for the `pageref` issue.

Comment: Michal, I added Update 1. But unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce the epubcheck error in a MWE. The error appears in connection with `\pageref`, both within `ordinary body of text` and within the `\pagenote{..}` command in the pagenote at the end of the document. With this: dont you suspect some fixing key for it?